# On chef recipe, where is the ssh key retrieved from ohai?

Tags: ssh, chef-infra

In a chef recipe if you do a `node["keys"]["ssh"]["host_rsa_public"]` it will retrieve the public part of a ssh key named host_rsa_public, even if you don't have anything inside `.ssh/`.

I'm going add this key to other nodes `.ssh/authorized_keys`, later when i try to connect using ssh, I will need to specify the path of that key file, but where is this key?

Comment: `node["keys"]["ssh"]` refers to the server (`sshd`), not client-side keys.  If you want to manage a user's authorized keys, you will need to do that another way.

Comment: A cookbook that I generated myself... 
Because Ohai retrieves information from the nodes using `node["parameter"]`  ... The same as going in the terminal and typing `ohai ssh`

Answer (score 0):

That's a host key, i.e. `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`. This is unrelated to user keys. It's the thing you see the fingerprint of when you get that modal "do you want to add this to known hosts?" every time you SSH to a new machine.